# flex-direction: 'row' s not working in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm stuck in one issue related to `flexDirection: 'row'`. I'm giving every style to `<View>` but it is not behaving like `flexDirection: 'row'`.

**My output** https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNOTF.png

I want to take all size tag in row and all color tag in row but it is not working.

**My code**

```
<View key={index}>
{
  count=count+1,
  this.state.data.variants.map((variants, index) => (
    option_values = variants.option_values,
    unique_size.indexOf(option_values[count].value) == -1 ?
      <View key={index} style={{flex: 1,}}>
        {
           unique_variant.indexOf(option_values[count].name) == -1 ?    
             <View>
             {                                           
                unique_variant.push(option_values[count].name),          
                <View style={{padding: 5}}>
                   <CapitalizedText style={{fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#585858'}}>{'Select ' + option_values[count].name}
                  </CapitalizedText>
                </View>
            }
            </View>
          : null
       }
       <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1,marginBottom: 5}}>
         {
            unique_size.push(option_values[count].value),
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} style={s.select_variants} key={index}
            >
               <Text style={s.select_size_txt}>{option_values[count].value}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        }
      </View>
    </View>
     : null
   ))
}</View>
```

I tried to give style in each `<View>` but I failed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give flexDirection row to the view that wraps the content what you want to display within a row, not to the views that gonna be on the row.

```
<View style = {{flexDirection:'row'}}>
    <ContentDisplayedOnARow/>
</View>

 <View  key={index}>
            {
                this.state.data.variants.map((variants, index) => (
                option_values = variants.option_values,
                unique_size.indexOf(option_values[index].value) === -1 ?
                <View  style = {{flexDirection:'row'}} key={index}>
                {
                    unique_variant.indexOf(option_values[index].name) === -1 ?
                        <View>
                            {
                                unique_variant.push(option_values[count].name),
                                <View style={{padding: 5}}>
                                    <CapitalizedText style={{fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#585858'}}>
                                        {'Select ' + option_values[index].name}
                                    </CapitalizedText>
                                </View>
                            }
                        </View>
                        : null
                }
                        <View style={{marginBottom: 5}}>
                        {
                            unique_size.push(option_values[count].value),
                            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} style={s.select_variants} key={index}>
                                 <Text style={s.select_size_txt}>{option_values[count].value}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        }
                        </View>
                </View>
                : null
                ))
            }</View>
```

Comment: yes I know this and tried too but it is not working. All titles and sizes are display in row

Comment: I think your code is missing a view, try wrapping the map with a view that has flexDirection row

Comment: no I put `<View>` around all respective .map and give `flexDirection: row` to respective `<View>` but it gives same result

Comment: that putting backgroundColor 'red', to see space that its occupying

Comment: it occupies all width of screen like I updated my image

Comment: you see, each component is being displayed with a horizontal view, but not within a horizontal view, the View that is above then should have this behavior

Comment: can you please indicate in my code where I've to add actually I tried to give `flexDirection: 'row'` in every `<View>` but unfortunate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172074/discussion-between-bruno-mazzardo-and-riddhi).

Comment: In order for flex direction to work it must be nested within a view that is at least a flex. So your parent view should be flex: 1.